# My api Returns strange values with php version up

Tags: php, reactjs, node.js, laravel, eloquent

I upgraded from php8.1 to 8.2 and my API is returning strange values.
Specifically, they are as follows
(Excerpts)
{"props":{"data":{"searchResponse":"\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0003m�y\u003c\u0013\n\u0000�q�\u003e\u000f��r|�\u00181�fiΑ�yn3�\u0019B9?�%D\u0016�'�1�+��q�s4f�����̑\u001aϹXn�E�}��~��*d1��

The searchResponse used to return correct JSON format data, but now returns garbled strings.

The response header is as follows

Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'none'
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

The request header is as follows

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br

Is the cause a compression error or something else?

I have tried the following settings on the server side and client side to solve the problem, but they did not resolve the issue.
1 I added the following settings to the client side, but the characters are garbled.
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'

2 I added these settings on the server side, but the garbled characters still remained.

$returnValue =new Resource($xxxx);
return $returnValue->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Can't be a compression error because other parts of your JSON look fine (ie `props`, `data` and `searchResponse`)

Comment: it would be nice if you could show how `searchResponse` data is being generated.

Comment: The following collection is created on the laravel side and returned to the caller.
The elements of the data array are about 20.
$x 
array (
  'data' => 
    'esearches' => \Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array(
       'items' => 
      array (
        0 =>  array (
          'type' => 2,
          'e_id' => 115,
          'c_service' => 
          array ('_id' => 0,///),
          'c_event' => array ('event_id' => 115,////)),),

return new Resource($x);

Comment: Is there a possible reason for this, such as an outdated compression library?

Comment: @Bagus

Dependency updates have been performed by COMPOSER.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return your object using

```
return json_encode($your_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried it, but it did not resolve the issue.